# PHP MySQL Json_encode display nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why my php display nothing. 
I have a dataBase Movies and I want put the elements of the base in a JSON.
However when I test the php with my localhost, I have nothing.

My dataBase Movies :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Movies` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Movies` (
`classment` INT NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`actors` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`kind` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`director` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'big5' NOT NULL,
`date` DATE NOT NULL,
`image` BLOB NULL,
`summary` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`classment`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I insert two movies into the dataBase :

```
INSERT INTO Movies (classment, title, actors, kind, director, date, image, summary)
VALUES ('1', 'The Lord of the rings : The fellowship of the rings', 'Elijah Wood, Ian McKellen, Viggo Mortensen', 'Adventure/Fantasy', 'Peter Jackson','19/12/2001', 'LOAD_FILE("/home/michael/Documents/Dkit/Master1/Semester2/Enterprise_Mobility/CA2/images/LoR1.jpeg")', 'A meek hobbit of the Shire and eight companions set out on a journey to Mount Doom to destroy the One Ring and the dark lord Sauron.' );

INSERT INTO Movies (classment, title, actors, kind, director, date, image, summary)
VALUES ('2', 'The Lord of the rings : The two towers', 'Elijah Wood, Ian McKellen, Viggo Mortensen', 'Adventure/Fantasy', 'Peter Jackson','18/12/2002', 'LOAD_FILE("/home/michael/Documents/Dkit/Master1/Semester2/Enterprise_Mobility/CA2/images/LoR2.jpeg")', 'While Frodo and Sam edge closer to Mordor with the help of the shifty Gollum, the divided fellowship makes a stand against Sauron\'s new ally, Saruman, and his hordes of Isengard.' );
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php

try{
 $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=movies', 'root', 'xxxx');
 $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 }catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
  die();
 }

// query the application data
$query = $handler->prepare('SELECT title, image FROM Movies');

//execute the prepared statement
$query->execute();

// an array to save the application data
$rows = array();

// iterate to query result and add every rows into array
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
}

$row1["ListMovies"] = $rows;
die(json_encode($row1));
?>
```

I want to obtain somethings like this : {"ListMovies":[]}

Thank you for your help

Michaël

Comment: Can you confirm that the page is getting to the final die() line by changing it to die("I AM HERE!");

Comment: When I change by die("I am her!"); nothing display also.

Comment: This suggests to me the issue is elsewhere. Add this right to the start of your script after <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Nothing. I have put before the try{, it's correct ?

Comment: Yup that's right... surprised you're not seeing anything, but I would suggest the issue is deeper than the json_encode part, your syntax looks fine to me!

Comment: Ok, thank but I don't see where can come from the problem

Comment: Check if the query return any value

Comment: Check my answer. **Your script runs to completion** _So this is not your problem_, you need to look at the javascript probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your php code requires no inputs you can just run it from the browser like a normal page.

So add some debug messages to it, so you can see where it is getting to, if anywhere.

```
<?php
echo 'HELLO<br>';

try{
 echo 'TRYING<br>';
 $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=movies', 'root', 'xxxx');
 $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 }catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
  die();
 }

// query the application data
echo 'BEFORE PREPARE<br>';

$query = $handler->prepare('SELECT title, image FROM Movies');

echo 'AFTER PREPARE<br>';

//execute the prepared statement
$query->execute();

echo 'AFTER EXECUTE<br>';

// an array to save the application data
$rows = array();

// iterate to query result and add every rows into array
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo '<pre>In While' . print_r($row,true) . '</pre>';
   $rows[] = $row;
}

$row1["ListMovies"] = $rows;
echo '<pre>' . print_r($row1,true) . '</pre>';

echo json_encode($row1);
exit;
?>
```

You should see from thsi where it is going wrong, or if in fact it is this script that is the issue at all.

**Additional info**

Well I took my own advice and as you were nice enough to provide the table definition and some sample data I created that database and loaded the data and ran your code.

It ran through to completion and generated the json string data. So this code is not your problem.

**RESULTS**

```
HELLO
TRYING
BEFORE PREPARE
AFTER PREPARE
AFTER EXECUTE

In WhileArray
(
    [title] => The Lord of the rings : The fellowship of the
    [image] => LOAD_FILE("/home/michael/Documents/Dkit/Master1/Semester2/Enterprise_Mobility/CA2/images/LoR1.jpeg")
)

In WhileArray
(
    [title] => The Lord of the rings : The two towers
    [image] => LOAD_FILE("/home/michael/Documents/Dkit/Master1/Semester2/Enterprise_Mobility/CA2/images/LoR2.jpeg")
)

Array
(
    [ListMovies] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => The Lord of the rings : The fellowship of the
                    [image] => LOAD_FILE("/home/michael/Documents/Dkit/Master1/Semester2/Enterprise_Mobility/CA2/images/LoR1.jpeg")
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => The Lord of the rings : The two towers
                    [image] => LOAD_FILE("/home/michael/Documents/Dkit/Master1/Semester2/Enterprise_Mobility/CA2/images/LoR2.jpeg")
                )

        )

)

{"ListMovies":[{"title":"The Lord of the rings : The fellowship of the","image":"LOAD_FILE(\"\/home\/michael\/Documents\/Dkit\/Master1\/Semester2\/Enterprise_Mobility\/CA2\/images\/LoR1.jpeg\")"},{"title":"The Lord of the rings : The two towers","image":"LOAD_FILE(\"\/home\/michael\/Documents\/Dkit\/Master1\/Semester2\/Enterprise_Mobility\/CA2\/images\/LoR2.jpeg\")"}]}
```

I would suggest you look at the table design as you are loading more than 45 chars into `title` and your INSERT has the `date` column incorrectly defined.

i.e. date in insert should be in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' or MySQL does not understand it as a date.

Answer (score 0):

I have this :

```
HELLO
TRYING
BEFORE PREPARE
AFTER PREPARE
AFTER EXECUTE

In WhileArray
(
[title] => The Lord of the rings : The fellowship of the
[image] => LOAD_FILE("/home/michael/Documents/Dkit/Master1/Semester2/Enterprise_Mobility/CA2/images/LoR1.jpeg")
)

In WhileArray
(
[title] => The Lord of the rings : The two towers
[image] => LOAD_FILE("/home/michael/Documents/Dkit/Master1/Semester2/Enterprise_Mobility/CA2/images/LoR2.jpeg")
)
Array
(
[ListMovies] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => The Lord of the rings : The fellowship of the
                [image] => LOAD_FILE("/home/michael/Documents/Dkit/Master1/Semester2/Enterprise_Mobility/CA2/images/LoR1.jpeg")
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => The Lord of the rings : The two towers
                [image] => LOAD_FILE("/home/michael/Documents/Dkit/Master1/Semester2/Enterprise_Mobility/CA2/images/LoR2.jpeg")
            )

    )

  )
```

But no the json_encode

Comment: Then change the `die(json_encode($row1));` to `echo json_encode($row1); exit;` Like I did in my answer.

Comment: It's work, I have change the date. So thank you at all to your help. Thank

Comment: Thats ok, just mark the answer as correct that lets other know when they come searching

Answer (score 0):

From the [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) manual page:

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

You don't have any reference to UTF-8 in your code. You don't even set the encoding when you connect to the database:

```
new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=movies', 'root', 'xxxx');
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'd expect to see `charset=utf8` or something else in the connection string.